# dynamic MYSQL query in stored procedure

Tags: mysql

> SELECT @query1 := GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SELECT * FROM asterisk.',
>   table_name)
>                                  SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ') AS CUSTOMQUERY FROM Information_Schema.tables WHERE  table_name LIKE '%custom%';
>   PREPARE stmt FROM @query1; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
>
> ..but at the end of the result we got missing query 
>   like SELECT * FROM
>   asterisk.custom_70003 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM asterisk.custom_70006
>   UNION ALL SELECT * FROM asterisk.custom_70007 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM
>   asterisk.custom_70010 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM asterisk.custom_70011
>   UNION ALL SELECT * FROM asterisk.custom_70042 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM
>   asterisk.custom_70043 UNION ALL SELECT * FRO  ..

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FRO' at line 1

so it gives me error

> ..I want to use this in my SSRS report .and ssrs querybuilder prompt
>   me for parameter .. so if we use this in procedure it will be benefit
>   for me.because in that way i can easily access this in my report.

Answer (score 0):

You should increase [group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) value.

From the documentation: `group_concat_max_len` is the maximum permitted result length in bytes for the GROUP_CONCAT() function. The default is 1024.